# How to show a module in productdetails page only in virtuemart

Tags: virtuemart

I want to show a level2 categories only in product details page in virtuemart,but there is no specific product details page

Answer (score 0):

You will need a component like [Metamod](http://www.metamodpro.com/) and use a recipe like:

> $vm = JomGenius("virtuemart"); // need this at the start of every rule
>
> if ($vm->check( "pagetype = productdetails" ) ) {   return 99; // module id }

Without Metamod you could use the following:

```
if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='productdetails') {
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$module = &JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom','Your module name');
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

Good Luck!